# Как на PHP отправлять запросы через file_get_contents через socks5 прокси?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, socks5

Получаю информацию с сторонних сайтов используя PHP функцию file_get_contents. Интересует как её можно использовать через socks5 прокси?
Да,- меня не забанили в google, искал, вот только почему то не нашёл решения.